# EF Core with PostgreSQL - Failing to create composite key

Tags: sql, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I am currently using EF Core with the NPGSQL (PostgreSQL) driver plugin to scaffold a database, however it looks like the EF code to create composite keys are not working as they would if I were using MSSQL. Here is my code:

```
public class Account
{
    public Account() => AccountReferences = new List<AccountReference>();

    public int Id { get; init; }

    public IEnumerable<AccountReference> AccountReferences;
}

public class AccountReference
{
    public int Id { get; init; }

    public Account Account { get; set; }

    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    public string Reference { get; set; }
}

internal sealed class AccountReferenceConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AccountReference>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AccountReference> builder)
    {
        builder.HasIndex(x => new { x.AccountId, x.Reference })
            .IsUnique();
    }
}
```

As you can see, Account and AccountReference has a one-to-many relationship with a composite key defined as AccountID and Reference. However when scaffolding this into a script I don't see any hint of the composite key being generated at all.

Can someone please assist me with what is going wrong here? It looks like some kind of bug to me unless I'm doing something wrong here.

Dependencies:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore v7.0.4
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools v7.0.4
- Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL v7.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realised that I was not including the `AccountReferenceConfiguration` in my `DbContext` class:

```
builder.ApplyConfiguration(new AccountReferenceConfiguration());
```

With this I can now see the generated composite keys:

```
        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_AccountReferences_AccountId_Reference",
            table: "AccountReferences",
            columns: new[] { "AccountId", "Reference" },
            unique: true);
```

Rookie move! *triple face palm*